# Consuming data from Kafka queue using Storm Toplology

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

The algorithm is reading data from Kafka queue using `KafkaSpout`.

I am facing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't initialize the topology
  at com.bridgera.iot.kafka.App.main(App.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Storm conf is not valid. Must be json-serializable
  at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:104)
  at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:70)
  at com.bridgera.iot.kafka.App.main(App.java:60)
```

My Java code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws AlreadyAliveException, InvalidTopologyException
{
    String nimbusHost = "localhost";
    ZkHosts zkHosts=new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
    String topic_name="test";
    String consumer_group_id="storm";
    String zookeeper_root="";
    SpoutConfig kafkaConfig=new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, 
            topic_name, zookeeper_root, consumer_group_id);
    kafkaConfig.scheme=new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);
    TopologyBuilder builder=new TopologyBuilder();
    //builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", kafkaSpout, 1);
    builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", kafkaSpout);
    builder.setBolt("PrinterBolt", new PrinterBolt()).globalGrouping("KafkaSpout");
    Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    conf.put(Config.TRANSACTIONAL_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181);
    conf.put(Config.TRANSACTIONAL_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, Arrays.asList("localhost"));
    conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT, 20000);
    conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 20000);
    conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_RETRY_TIMES, 3);
    conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_RETRY_INTERVAL, 30);
    LocalCluster cluster=new LocalCluster();
    try{
        cluster.submitTopology("KafkaConsumerTopology", conf, builder.createTopology());
        Thread.sleep(120000);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't initialize the topology", e);
    }
}
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here in the configuration.
FYI: I am running Zookeeper and Storm JVM (local execution) in an AWS cluster.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error. Btw: your code an stack trace do not match: in your code, you use `LocalCluster` but your stack trace says `StormSubmitter`. In which case it does fail? Did you try to start with an empty Config and add parameters one by one to see which one yield the problem?

Comment: @Sax i didn't tried like that, i will try it now. I am just running this class file in amazon aws cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<String> hosts = Arrays.asList("localhost")
conf.put(Config.TRANSACTIONAL_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, hosts);
```

I think is a problem with `java.util.AbstractList<Object>` returned from `Arrays.asList("localhost")` and the parsing to json.